# Function for adjusted Rsquare on test data?

Tags: r, validation, regression, data-science

w.r.t  R/Rstudio  I know there is RMSE and R2 function which i can leverage to calculate RMSE and Rsquare on test data.  Is there a similar function for adjusted R square on test data?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It is very unclear what types of test you are talking about.

Comment: Base R has no functions called R2 or RMSE.  Are you using some library?

Comment: Any answer would depend on the model you are using. There is no R square of your data.

Comment: Questions such as this need to include code and data.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the Adjusted R-squared for *any* model by simply ... adjusting R-squared.
The formula is available from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2).

> AdjR2 = 1 - (1 - R2) * (n-1) / (n-k-1)
>   where n = number of points
>   and   k = number of variables in the model

Here is a simple example:

```
library(MASS)
data(Boston)

LM <- lm(medv~., data=Boston)
R2 = summary(LM)$r.squared
R2
dim(Boston)

summary(LM)$adj.r.squared
[1] 0.7337897

1 - (1 - R2)*(dim(Boston)[1]-1)/(dim(Boston)[1]-dim(Boston)[2])
[1] 0.7337897
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are referring to the adjusted R squared from a linear model it can be extracted from the output of `summary.lm`.  Using the built in BOD data.frame for purposes of example:

```
s <- summary(lm(demand ~ Time, BOD))
s$adj.r.squared
## [1] 0.5561503
```

Try `str(s)` to see the various items you can get from `summary.lm` in much the same manner.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did use it when building the model. Wanted on which I can use on the test data. No worries, i got it

Answer (score 0):

A number of base functions in `R` will output an adjusted R2. It just depends on what the objective or context is. For example, if the goal is to calculate the fit of a linear model with the `lm()` function,

```
x <- rnorm( 10 )
y <- rnorm( 10 )
linear_model <- lm( y~x )
summary( linear_model )
```

The output would include the adjusted R-square for fitting that linear model:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.5876 -0.5203  0.1511  0.4593  1.1989 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -0.2018     0.2777  -0.727    0.488
x            -0.4355     0.3696  -1.178    0.272

Residual standard error: 0.8748 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1479,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.0414 
F-statistic: 1.389 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.2725
```

But again, this value is ONLY in reference for fitting a linear model to the data, and is simply an illustration that `R` may report it with certain functions.